# Put content of wordpress page inside div

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to put content of wordpress page content inside div but that does not work ,

simply trying ot do that

```
echo '<div style="display:none">' . the_content . '</div>';
```

but it is rather than showing content inside div it is showing each of them the content and divs not echoing like that
thanks in advance

Comment: `the_content` would refer to a _constant_ - which in all likelyhood, does not exist. To call the _function_ by that name, you need to append round brackets - `the_content()`

Comment: I have done both of them -_-

Comment: This function only works when used inside "the loop" - if you are outside of that context, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142957/use-the-content-outside-the-loop

Answer (score 0):

you can get content by using this code and also you have to remove style from your div

```
echo '<div>' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
```